# How to disable mouseEvent during pinch zoom?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QGraphicsItem` I have implemented `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` for press and drag.

I also implemented the pinch-gesture for pinch zoom.

However I found during pinch zoom, the mouse events are also triggered because the touch events are auto translated into mouse events by `sceneEvent()`.

How could I disable the mouse events when I have two touch points for pinch zoom?

Comment: Return true or explicitly accepting the event ( event->accept();) didn't stop the generation of mouseMoveEvent! It was tested in Qt 5.5 and also one observation was mouseMoveEvent was generated before gesture event was generated while doing the pinch operation, so in my view there is something else to be configured in addition to the above. note: in the program I am debugging Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents attribute is set to true explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to accept the touch events to avoid them being translated to mouse events. There is also `Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents` attribute that enforces transaltion of unaccepted touch events, which is enabled by default:

> All touch events that are not accepted by the application will be
>   translated to left button mouse events instead. This attribute is
>   enabled by default.

Comment: But how can I accpet the touch events when there are two touch points and still allow the event to be translated into mouseEvent when there is only one touch point?

Comment: Something like `bool sceneEvent() { if (e->touchPoints().count() == 2) return true; }`